# Weird scenario when I use jQuery validation remote

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin and I am calling a remote validator like this

In this I have set the rule for remote like this

```
rules: {
    NickName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        remote: {
            url: '/Employee/IsNickNameTaken',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                nickName: function () {
                    return $('#NickName').val();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    },
    messages: {
    NickName: {
        required: "Nick name is required.",
        minlength: "Nick name should be 3 characters."
    }
}
```

My controller is this

```
public ActionResult IsNickNameTaken(string nickName)
{
    var result = EmployeeManager.IsNickNameTaken(nickName) ? "Nick name is already taken. Try another!": "";
    return Json(result);
}
```

And if I pass a NickName, I get this error message

> "Nick name is already taken. Try another!"

[image]

As you can see my error message comes enclosed in quotes. Why is this happening? How to solve this?

Comment: try $('#NickName').html() instead of .val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have specified `dataType: 'text'` for your remote rule. That will be passed as the dataType option for the jQuery ajax call. That means jQuery is not interpreting the response as a json object, it will instead be returned as text. See dataType option of the jQuery [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You just need to update your rule configuration to tell jQuery the response should be interpreted as json. You could either specify `dataType: 'json'` or even remove that line, as the default value used by the remote rule is json:

```
remote: {
   url: '/Employee/IsNickNameTaken',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
       nickName: function () {
           return $('#NickName').val();
       }
   }
}
```

See the remote validation method [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).